# find the file I upload from a multiple input file in php

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have an input file set to multiple `<input type="file" multiple/>`

When I was on javascript, I could use this proprety  `document.getElementById("myFile").files` to access to all the files I had uploaded.

Now I am in PHP and I don't know how to find the file I uploaded. I know that they could probably be in **$_FILES**, but how can I access to the files.

Comment: if you'd bothered to do `var_dump($_FILES)`, you'd see `['tmp_name']`, which is where PHP stored the file TEMPORARILY for you to deal with...

Comment: That a nice advice,i don't know why but I only see one file if i upload 5 files in my html page ?

Comment: you didn't tell php to expect multiple files. if a form field name gets re-used, PHP will simply overwrite earlier copies of the that name's data with later ones. using `name="foo[]"` (the `[]` particularly)` tells php to expect multiple different sets of data and to build an array of values.

Comment: I saw it on previous post from other people, but thanks to 
confirmed. But how i can access to the name of the first file i uploaded.

Comment: var_dump will show you. $_FILES is an array like any other php array, and there's nothing special about how you access things in it.

Comment: Thanks you, i don't know how to upvote your comment sorry

Answer (score 0):

Like

```
$property_images = $_FILES['property_images']['name'];
    if(!empty($property_images))
    {
        for($up=0;$up<count($property_images);$up++)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['property_images']['tmp_name'][$up],'../images/property_images/'.$_FILES['property_images']['name'][$up]);
        }
    }
```